# How to catch OutOfMemoryError in JVM and run a script if it's caught?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, jvm-arguments

I have a program that sometimes throw OOME, 
I understand that there is a flag in the JVM options that I can set and whenever a certain Error/Exception appears (such as OOME) it calls a script I wrote.
The script will give the user a notification and will call a the program with a different argument so it won't get OOME again.

does anyone know how to set this flag? what is the JVM options I need to set?
I looked everywhere on line and couldn't find the answer.

help me please!
Thanks,
Aye

Comment: type 'java -X' at the command prompt. You will get a list of all the extended options. Might help.

Answer (score 15):

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="cmd args;cmd args"`

From: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#DebuggingOptions

Comment: wow, that one looks useful, I will check it out now. thanks :)

Answer (score -4):

I found one suggestion in a [forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=4055998#4055998): catch the OOME in your application (like directly in main,  assuming you're single threaded) and do this in the catch handler:

```
catch (OutOfMemoryError not_again) {
  System.gc();
  System.runFinalization();
  System.gc();
  System.out.println("Your error message");
}
```

Cleaning up the heap might free just enough memory to produce a last error message before dying.

Comment: thanks, but the application is very sparse and I don't want to catch it inside I prefer to call .dat file from the JVM itself

Comment: one would think that the JVM would attempt a few rounds of GC before throwing an OOME itself; this isn't guaranteed to really do much of anything.