# How can I restart JVM on OutOfMemoryError _after_ making a heap dump?

Tags: jvm, java

I know about the [`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542979/260805) JVM parameter. I also know about [`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="cmd args;cmd args"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821180/260805) and that `kill -3 <JVM_PID>` will request a heap dump.

**Question:** How can I make sure that I, on `OutOfMemoryError`, first make a full heap dump and *then* force a restart (or kill) after the dump is done? Is my best bet `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -3 %p;sleep <time-it-takes-to-dump>;kill -9 %p"`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to monitor the process from without the jvm, and restart it accordingly, e.g. unix script, monitorying system? if the jvm is out of memory i would not want to rely on it to be able to reliably launch a command to restart itself

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" TestApp
```

JVM will dump heap first, and then execute OnOutOfMemoryError commands [(proof)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/utilities/debug.cpp#l295).

Answer (score 26):

If you just want to shutdown you can use one of the following parameters:

- `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError`

The VM arguments were added in Java version 8u92, see the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html).

> **ExitOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   When you enable this option, the JVM exits on the
>   first occurrence of an out-of-memory error. It can be used if you
>   prefer restarting an instance of the JVM rather than handling out of
>   memory errors.
>
> **CrashOnOutOfMemoryError**
>   If this option is enabled, when an
>   out-of-memory error occurs, the JVM crashes and produces text and
>   binary crash files.

Enhancement Request: [JDK-8138745](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138745) (parameter naming is wrong though  [JDK-8154713](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154713), `ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` instead of `ExitOnOutOfMemory`)

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are these flags mutually exclusive?

Comment: @gregsilin  looking at the [changeset in mercurial](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/rev/cbc2d5fbdae1#l2.8), it looks like crashing will be given preference when both options are provided

Answer (score 0):

I bet the runtime sets a specific errorlevel on crash. Check for that return code and rerun the program in that case. You should perhaps put that into a script.

The sun jre allows you to heap dump on oome, perhaps openjdk does too.