# how to set the java dump file location for the tanuki wrapper

Tags: java, configuration, jvm, wrapper, dump

how can I set the DUMP file location for the Tanuki wrapper.

I need to write the DUMP file when the OutOfMemoryError occurs. This is configured as follows:

```
wrapper.filter.trigger.1=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1=DUMP,RESTART
```

But I need to store it to a different disk partition to prevent a total crash due to disk memory.

I found some JVM properties but they seem not to work:

```
wrapper.java.additional.18=-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:/test1
```

Description:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof  Path to directory or filename for heap dump.
```

This one is not needed in my case --> HeapDump is being  written with the above config..-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Can anyone help me in this term.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I use myself in production:

```
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:HeapDumpPath=C:/test1
```

In this case `wrapper.filter` configuration is not needed.

Note that `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` option appeared in JDK 8u92. If you use earlier version of JDK, the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538591/3448419) may help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I also tried it this way. but the dump files are always stored in the folder where the java application has been started.

Comment: @izocan There might be a mistake in the configuration. Check `jcmd PID VM.flags` to verify that JVM options have been applied correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. The problem was that I started the Application within eclipse. My eclipse is starting the application with the IBM JDK and because of this the JVM Parameter is not taking action. when I started the .bat file from the WindowsExplorer everything works fine.